# Is there a post-cap connector I can use to secure 2x10 joists to a 4x6 post?

Tags: deck, post

I'm fixing up a 10x15 (roughly) feet deck and need to replace the one rotten outer rim joist. The current post is notched and the joists are sitting on top of the post bolted to the notched post. I want to cut the post level to the bottom of the rim joists but I need something to connect the posts to the rim joists here. Is there any connector available I can get for my purpose? I was looking at Simpson LCE4Z but those are rated for at most 6x nominals only.

[image: corner post where rim joists connect]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [LCE specs](https://www.strongtie.com/twopiecepostcaps_postcaps/lce_cap/p/lce#:%7E:text=can%20accommodate%204x%20and%206x%20lumber) indicate suitability for 4-by lumber. Joist height is irrelevant. The nominal product code relates to post size, not joist height. You don't need such a plate to span the entire height of the joist. Take a look at the diagrams under Installation.